# Makefile target dependency from a file list

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have three source files: `a`, `b` and `c` in `src1`, `src2` and `src3`, respectively.

I have the following Makefile:

```
ROOT1=$(shell realpath ./src1)
ROOT2=$(shell realpath ./src2)
ROOT3=$(shell realpath ./src3)

SOURCE_FILES = $(shell cat depsfromfile.list)

.PHONY: compile

compile: .xsim.timestamp
    @echo $(SOURCE_FILES)
    @echo "simulating..."

.xsim.timestamp: $(SOURCE_FILES)
    @echo "compiling source files"
    @touch .xsim.timestamp

.PHONY: clean

clean: 
    @rm -rf .*.timestamp
```

I'm using the following `depsfromfile.list` file:

```
$(ROOT1)/a
$(ROOT2)/b
$(ROOT3)/c
```

As you can see, I'm using `$(ROOT1)` variable in the `.list` file. I'm assuming that when the values are being assigned to `SOURCE_FILES` variable, `$(ROOT1)` is evaluated. However, running the make file gives the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '$(ROOT1)/a', needed by '.xsim.timestamp'.  Stop.
```

My goal is to take the list of source files from a file. Please guide how can I achieve this.

What I have tried so far:

I have changed the line `.xsim.timestamp: $(SOURCE_FILES)` to `.xsim.timestamp: $($(SOURCE_FILES))`. Now, the make runs as expected for the first time, but does not detect changes in the source files.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
.
+-- src1
|   +-- a
+-- src2
|   +-- b
+-- src3
|   +-- c
+-- Makefile
+-- depsfromfile.list
```

The contents of the files `a`, `b` and `c` are irrelevant.

If I hardcode the fullpaths of files in `depsfromfile.list` everything works smoothly. However, I want the source paths to be taken from Makefile variables like `ROOT1`, `ROOT2` and `ROOT3`. The reason for this requirement is that some tools use the same flist as their input and it is preferable to have only one file where source files are defined.

Comment: "*I'm assuming that when the values are being assigned to SOURCE_FILES variable, $(ROOT1) is evaluated.*" -- that would be incorrect. The *arguments* to the function are subject to variable expansion, but the result is not.

Comment: What you present won't work, and it seems way overengineered. I wouldn't define those `ROOT*` variables at all, and I probably wouldn't put the dependency list in a separate file.  If I *did* put it in a separate file then I would use makefile syntax so that the main makefile could just `include` it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you please explain what syntax should I be including in the Makefile? Did you mean just declaring a target in the separate file Makefile with manual listing of different source files? The reason to put flist is that it is being used in other programs as well that take input in the form of flist. It will be easier and more compliant to the DRY (Don't repeat yourself) to define the files in one place and use in multiple other places.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the comment by @johnbollinger pointed me to the right direction. The idea is to take the source list file and generate a make file with the help of `sed` command. Once done, we can include the generated `mk` file to the main make file. The updated Makefile is given below:

```
ROOT1=$(shell realpath ./src1)
ROOT2=$(shell realpath ./src2)
ROOT3=$(shell realpath ./src3)

-include depsfromfile.mk

.xsim.timestamp: depsfromfile.mk $(SOURCE_FILES) 
    @echo "compiling source files"
    @touch .xsim.timestamp

.PHONY: compile
compile: .xsim.timestamp
    @echo "simulating..."

depsfromfile.mk: depsfromfile.list
    @sed 's/^/SOURCE_FILES+=/' depsfromfile.list > depsfromfile.mk

.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    @rm -rf .*.timestamp *.mk
```